# Wrap a string like a file in Node.Js?

Tags: node.js

Not quite sure how this works. I have a cli tool I am using in Node that generates an image. It takes in a filepath as a parameter:

`tool --file fileName.md`

Unfortunately, what I have at the time of this execution are the contents of the file, not an actual file. What is the most appropriate way of somehow wrapping the text in a way that the `cli` tool could understand?

Currently, I am writing the contents to `/tmp` but I feel it's inefficient

Comment: "I am writing the contents to /tmp but I feel it's inefficient" - that's what I would do, what's the problem with it? and what kind of solution are you looking for?

Comment: Are you hitting any real world constraints? Just having something *feel* inefficient doesn't mean that it really is. You need to benchmark it to check.

Comment: The tool should preferably support pipes, then you can stream data to it.